# Delay a For Loop

Tags: javascript, settimeout

I am trying to create a FOR loop that removes an element every 1000ms instead of rushing instantaneously through the array and perform the operations.

I am doing this for reasons of performance since going normally through the loop freezes my UI.

```
 function removeFunction (i,selected) {
    selected[i].remove(); 
    }

function startLoop() {
        var selected = paper.project.selectedItems;
        for (var i = 0; i < selected.length; i++) {
            if (selected[i].name === "boundingBoxRect") continue;
          setTimeout(removeFunction(i,selected),1000)

        }

    }
```

It seems that the selected[i].remove() method is getting called without any delay. Why is that? Since I have set a Timeout of 1000ms shouldn't the items get removed with 1000ms interval between each?

**Note**

*In the code above, I am skipping an item called boundingBoxRect since I don't want to remove that. Just stating this so there is no confusion*

Comment: `setTimeout(function() removeFunction(i, selected); },1000);`

Comment: @putvande: No, that won't remove anything. It'll schedule repeated attempts to remove the element at `selected[selected.length]`, where (of course) there isn't one. Closures get an *enduring reference* to the variable, not a *copy* of the variable as of when they're created.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Simply turn it into a recursive function:

```
function removeFunction (i, selected) {
    // If i is equal to the array length, prevent further execution
    if (i === selected.length)
        return;

    // Remove ith child of selected array
    selected[i].remove();

    // Trigger same function after 1 second, incrementing i
    setTimeout(function() {
        removeFunction(++i,selected)
    }, 1000);
}

// Trigger the function to begin with, passing in 0 as i
removeFunction(0, paper.project.selectedItems);
```

Here's a [**JSFiddle demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/kF4VV/) (using `console.log` instead of `selected[i].remove()`, as you haven't provided a definition for that function);

Comment: Well, taking a look, this still calls `removeFunction` immediately. You're not passing any functions to `setTimeout`. You're doing the removals immediately, and repeatedly passing `undefined` into `setTimeout`.

Comment: @T.J.Crowder ooh, I thought I'd changed that. The JSFiddle uses the correct code - simply forgot to include it here.

Comment: As of the latest edit, it doesn't anymore. *(Edit: Overlapping comments there. :-) )*

Answer (score 1):

> It seems that the selected[i].remove() method is getting called without any delay. Why is that?

Because that's what you're telling it to do. `setTimeout(removeFunction(i,selected),1000)` *calls* `removeFunction` immediately and passes its return value into `setTimeout`, exactly the way `foo(bar())` *calls* `bar` and passes its return value into `foo`.

You can get the effect you want by using a builder function:

```
setTimeout(buildRemover(i,selected),1000);
```

...where `buildRemover` is:

```
function buildRemover(index, array) {
    return function() {
        removeFunction(index, array);
    };
}
```

Note how `buildRemover` creates a function that closes over the `index` and `array` variables. Then it returns a reference to that function, which is what gets scheduled via `setTimeout`. When the timeout occurs, that generated function is called, and it calls `removeFunction` with the appropriate values.

You can also do something similar using ES5's `Function#bind`:

```
setTimeout(removeFunction.bind(null, i, selected),1000);
```

`Function#bind` returns a new function that, when called, will call the original (`removeFunction` above) use the given `this` value (`null` in our example) and arguments.